# Issues with Json Parsing of HTML Href Tag

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, coldfusion

I am following a code with AngularJS and Coldfusion and trying to Parse the JSON, with cfc i am getting the Data in JSON format as:

```
[{"HIRE_DATE":"26 Jun 86","FIRST_NAME":"<a href=javascript:void(0);>Georgi<\/a>","EMP_NO":10001,"BIRTH_DATE":"02 Sep 53"},{"HIRE_DATE":"21 Nov 85","FIRST_NAME":"<a href=javascript:void(0);>Bezalel<\/a>","EMP_NO":10002,"BIRTH_DATE":"02 Jun 64"},{"HIRE_DATE":"28 Aug 86","FIRST_NAME":"<a href=javascript:void(0);>Parto<\/a>","EMP_NO":10003,"BIRTH_DATE":"03 Dec 59"},{"HIRE_DATE":"01 Dec 86","FIRST_NAME":"<a href=javascript:void(0);>Chirstian<\/a>","EMP_NO":10004,"BIRTH_DATE":"01 May 54"},{"HIRE_DATE":"12 Sep 89","FIRST_NAME":"<a href=javascript:void(0);>Kyoichi<\/a>","EMP_NO":10005,"BIRTH_DATE":"21 Jan 55"},{"HIRE_DATE":"02 Jun 89","FIRST_NAME":"<a href=javascript:void(0);>Anneke<\/a>","EMP_NO":10006,"BIRTH_DATE":"20 Apr 53"},{"HIRE_DATE":"10 Feb 89","FIRST_NAME":"<a href=javascript:void(0);>Tzvetan<\/a>","EMP_NO":10007,"BIRTH_DATE":"23 May 57"},{"HIRE_DATE":"15 Sep 94","FIRST_NAME":"<a href=javascript:void(0);>Saniya<\/a>","EMP_NO":10008,"BIRTH_DATE":"19 Feb 58"}]
```

The Issue with this is, it is loading in the ng-grid as it is:

***hire_date     first_name                                 emp_no         birthdate

12 sep 89       `<a href=javascript:void(0);>Anneke</a>`       10005            20 apr 53***

So it is not rendering as a link so as i can click to open,

here is the angular JS Code

```
if (searchText) {
                var ft = searchText.toLowerCase();
                $http.get('workData.cfc?method=getEmployees&returnformat=json').success(function (largeLoad) {      
                    data = largeLoad.filter(function(item) {
                            return JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase().indexOf(ft) != -1;
                    });
                    $scope.myData = angular.fromJson(data);
                    $scope.setPagingData($scope.myData,page,pageSize);
                });            
            } else {
                $http.get('workData.cfc?method=getEmployees&returnformat=json').success(function (largeLoad) {
                    $scope.myData = angular.fromJson(largeLoad);
                    $scope.setPagingData($scope.myData,page,pageSize);
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure if the following is totaly correct - can't check this right now. At least the idea should be valid!

The default `cellTemplate` the will be used by the `ngGrid` is:

```
<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()">
  <span ng-cell-text>{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</span>
</div>
```

As you can see your `FIRST_NAME` is included by an inline expression - e.g. `{{}}`, so angular will escape all your content.

You have to make sure that your content geos through the `$sce.trustAsHtml` function and is included by `ng-bind-html`. I would define a function in your controller like this:

```
$scope.trust = function(value){
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(value);
}
```

After that you have to define your own `cellTemplate` like this:

```
<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()">
  <span ng-cell-text ng-html-bind="trust(row.getProperty(col.field))"></span>
</div>
```

and configure your cell definition:

```
columnDefs: [
  { field: 'FIRST_NAME', 
    displayName: 'First Name',  
    cellTemplate: '<div> ... </div>' }, ...
```

More information about how to templating ngGrid is available at the github wiki: https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/wiki/Templating

Comment: Thanks for the Update, but i have solved that, and thanks again for giving additional things usability like trust